# torque qsub mpiexec error. Errno:9

Tags: errno, pbs, torque, mpiexec

I have installed Torque 4.2.0 on a Raspberry Pi cluster with 2 nodes. Installed Torque_server and torque_sched on server and torque_mom on the nodes. I managed to run qsub scripts successfully, but, after installing "the other" mpiexec ( as suggested here: http://www.cslu.ogi.edu/~zak/debianclusters/MPICH_with_Torque_Functionality ), if I run a qsub script running mpiexec I get the following error:

**socket_connect error (VERIFY THAT trqauthd IS RUNNING)
Error in connection to trqauthd (-1)-[cannot connect to port -1 in socket_connec
t_addr - errno:9 Bad file descriptor]
Error communicating with MasterCruz2(172.20.45.225)
mpiexec: Error: get_hosts: pbs_connect: no error.**

I have done some research but couldn't find nothing but an old email with a dead end.
Any help or ideas?

Comment: Can you make mpiexec work from the command line across both nodes from both nodes?

Comment: Yes, before installing torque, I am working with normal mpiexec in command line: mpiexec-f filenodes -n 2 program, where filenodes had IPs of the nodes. as I say the problem is when the "other" mpiexec is used for scripts in torque.

Comment: Ok. I understand now that the "other" mpiexec works around having to start the MPI daemons on the nodes. The page in your question appears to be a bit dated and since you've had success with the original mpiexec I would consider using it instead of the "other" version. Take a look at the three lines here that run mpdboot, mpiexec, and mpdallexit using $PBS_NODEFILE. If that doesn't work you might want to do some additional testing of your Torque environment.

Comment: I managed to solve this by installing the torque packges generated during the Make process on the nodes (devel, client, mom).

Comment: I managed to solve this by installing the packages generated during tha Make process on the nodes (doc, client, mom). However, another error has been found, I will be posting a new question; if you can help me I'd appreciate. I will mark this question as solved.

Comment: Is the trqauthd daemon running?